# How to pass settings to comment_form() if theme only uses comments_template()?

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I have a theme which uses comments_template() to write a comment form and existing comments to a page. It appears that comments_template() calls comment_form() internally which writes the form that allows the user to submit a comment.

comment_form() takes an array of various settings for the form.

My problem is that I can't pass my array directly to comment_form() because the theme only uses comments_template.

1) Is there a way to pass the array arg through comments_template?

2) Can I override comment_form() in functions.php so that whenever it is called, my args will automatically be passed in. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'first_setting' => 'some value',
    'another_setting' => 'another value'
);
function my_comment_form($args){
    comment_form($arg);
}
add_action('write_comments_form','my_comment_form') //does an action like 'write_comments_form' exist?
```

I want my changes to be global, so setting these values here is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this too complicated.

The comment_form_default filter can be used to set arguments for comment_form():
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_defaults/